# Pass by reference-only compile-time custom enum class in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm thinking about a custom enum class that will contain some built-in types data members and members of the string_view type. I want to prevent arbitrary instances of this enum type from being created, ditto for copying. The intention is to pass this enum's values around safely by reference only. It seems like a good idea for it to be a compile-time entity as well. Is something like below not too ridiculous and satisfies my goals? I wish I could make the values (i.e. T1, T2) to be static members of the MyEnum class Java-enum class style, but I don't think it is possible in C++ with constexpr, so that's the reason for the MyEnumValues value container.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyEnum {
    enum Type { t1, t2 };
    constexpr operator Type() const { return type_; }
    constexpr Type type() const { return type_; }
    constexpr string_view name() const { return name_; }
    constexpr bool operator==(const MyEnum& other) const { return type_ == other.type_; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(const MyEnum& other) const { return type_ != other.type_; }

    MyEnum(const MyEnum&) = delete;
    MyEnum(const MyEnum&&) = delete;
    MyEnum& operator=(const MyEnum&) = delete;
    MyEnum& operator=(const MyEnum&&) = delete;

private:
    constexpr MyEnum(Type type, string_view name) : type_(type), name_(name) {}
    Type type_;
    string_view name_;
    friend class MyEnumValues;
};

struct MyEnumValues {
    inline static constexpr MyEnum T1{MyEnum::t1, "t1"sv};
    inline static constexpr MyEnum T2{MyEnum::t2, "t2"sv};

    MyEnumValues() = delete;
};

void doSomethingWithEnum(const MyEnum& e) {
    switch (e) {
    case MyEnum::t1: cout << "saw t1" << endl; break;
    case MyEnum::t2: cout << "saw t2" << endl; break;
    default: assert(0); break;
    }
}

void printEnumName(const MyEnum& e) {
    cout << e.name() << endl;
}

int main() {
    doSomethingWithEnum(MyEnumValues::T2);
    doSomethingWithEnum(MyEnumValues::T1);
    printEnumName(MyEnumValues::T2);
    printEnumName(MyEnumValues::T1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever want such a type? I can understand non-copyable types for when copying them is inappropriate or fundamentally against the type's purpose. But it's an enumerator that contains a string_view. Why do you *care* if someone copies it?

Comment: @NicolBolas  My thinking, perhaps flawed, is that I want to pass it by reference to avoid unnecessary copying. It will contain more members than shown here, but I suppose not too many so that's a real performance concern. And if I design my classes around this enum so that they maintain references to enum values I want to make sure I don't hold on to a reference that goes out of scope or deleted.

Comment: *avoid unnecessary copying* But it only has an enum type and two pointers.  My platform, as measured, the cutoff for by-reference-vs-by-value is if the by value (of all the parameters) is bigger than 256 bytes.  256-512 being the break-even zone.

Comment: @Eljay I see what you're saying, so I won't gain any performance gains if my enum grows over certain size, and in your example passing by value won't be worse than passing by reference unless enum grows over 256 bytes. With that, yes, I'm probably over-complicating it .

Comment: @VladG: "*I want to pass it by reference to avoid unnecessary copying*" It is not your job to tell people what to do with the types you create. If a type cannot suffer copying (`unique_ptr`, `scoped_lock`, etc), that's one thing. But you shouldn't disallow it because you think copying 24 bytes of data is too much.

Comment: @NicolBolas it will be more than 24 but point taken. I'll just pass it by copy to keep it simple, and as Eljay suggests there won't be any performance penalty in doing so. Thanks!

Comment: As far as limiting the set of allowed enum values, is using a friend container with a private ctor a reasonable approach?

Comment: @VladG: "*I'll just pass it by copy to keep it simple*" **You** don't "pass it" by anything. How it gets passed around is none of your concern. You *allow* it to be passed by copy, but you don't make anyone do it. If they want to pass it by `const&`, that's their business. If they want to copy it, that's their business too. "*it will be more than 24 but point taken*" Unless your enumeration is more than 8 bytes, it will be 24: 8 for the enum+padding, 16 for the `string_view` (8 for the pointer, 8 for the size).

Comment: @NicolBolas just to clarify there is no them. This enum will primarily be used in the collection of classes that I create, so it is for my own consumption for the most part. So I will copy it as needed instead of keeping a reference, that's what I meant by "pass by copy" which is technically incorrect.

Comment: To really understand the difference in performance for by-reference and by-value, you'd need to implement both (preferably in your real app, and not just a contrived toy app), and profile to see if there is an appreciable difference in the optimized code.  (Compiler optimizers are wickedly clever.)  My anecdotal evidence for my platform may (or may not) be applicable to your scenario.  If it is a concern:  profile & measure.